# possible to auto zoom out if user's resolution < x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my site is aimed purely at the laptop market (dont ask why or argue!), all my users (or 95%+) we on a screen width of 1200+,

netbooks are now taking off, with a resolution of 1024 wide.

my site still looks great on a netbook if you zoom out once (ctrl-minus), but i don't want to rely on users knowing about ctrl-minus.

what are my options besides redesign? I'm keen not to have zoom buttons on my page.

**is there a javascript zoomer outer?!!!**

Comment: Good question actually. I don't think there is a global mechanism for this that interfaces with the browser's zoom functions but we will see.

Comment: Without pretending to know your audience or site, would zooming-out not make the text trickier to read (as it would be smaller)? Ideally, I think you should invest some time to remove the dependency you have on 'non-flexible widths' - but good luck all the same and I hope you're able to find a solution. :)

Answer (score 5):

While this doesn't sort out your zoom, you could try a little trick based on CSS & relative sizing.

If you have an image or a container that is `100px` wide, try setting it to `10em` wide (or faff with the `em` amount until you find the appropriate value). Eventually, if you do this to every single dimension specified upon your site, you'd be able to actively shrink the page by changing the default `font-size`. E.g. from 1em, to 0.91em.

People often use the relative sizing to allow people the flexibility of being able to shrink and grow font sizes as they want. It's not as commonly used on images (because they are by requirement, fixed in size). This needn't be the case though, and in this instance, might offer you a way out of a "full site redesign" and giving the effect of "zooming".

This might solve the problem without redesign, but may be tricky and would require a bit of testing. The way stylesheets cascade, shrinking the font a little more, element by element, might cause a few issues.

Comment: that's quite an ingenious little fix!

Comment: Very interesting indeed. I always wondered why the hell people used em.

Answer (score 0):

- detect screen resolution via JS
- apply appropriate CSS

ctrl + - is the browser feature and you should never rely on that.

try this article http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/
or try to google "javascript switch css"

Comment: i have some non-flexible widths so this would require a redesign.

i'm searching for a way to scale the whole page like zoom does

Answer (score 0):

this is a bad idea for many reasons. zooming is client specific so you will run into cross browser compatibilities if even possible at all. your best bet is to use css and set a min and/or max width. you don't need to redesign but (assuming proper html structure and usage of external css) changing some width values should do the trick.